# Protobuf-java: Merge two proto objects without concatenating repeated fields

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

I want to merge two complex proto objects `protoA` and `protoB` of the same type, where if a field is set in both the objects, the value of `protoB` should be set in the resulting proto.

I could use the `.mergeFrom()` function:

```
protoA.toBuilder().mergeFrom(protoB).build()
```

but according to the docs, repeated fields will be concatenated.

> mergeFrom(Message other): (builder only) merges the contents of other into this message, overwriting singular scalar fields, merging composite fields, and concatenating repeated fields.

I don't want this behaviour. Is there a elegant way to do this than to manually set each repeated fields?

Answer (score 3):

In `FieldMaskUtil` from protobuf there is an option to merge overriding existing fields.

It has a `MergeOptions` where you can configure `setReplaceRepeatedFields(true);` it will merge protoB into protoA taking protoB fields when repeated.

I will write you an example:

```
FieldMaskUtil.MergeOptions options = 
      new FieldMaskUtil.MergeOptions().setReplaceRepeatedFields(true);

// Now we get all the names of the fields in your proto
List<String> names = YourObjectProto.YourObject.getDescriptor().getFields()
           .stream().map(Descriptors.FieldDescriptor::getName)
           .collect(Collectors.toList());

FieldMaskUtil.merge(FieldMaskUtil.fromStringList(names),
      protoB, protoA.toBuilder(),options);
```

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't respect the options more than one level deep. See [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/java/util/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/util/FieldMaskTree.java#L331). So you will end up calling mergeFrom on child messages. :/

Comment: @daltonfury42, did you find a way to replace all the repeated fields in the hierarchy. ?