# Protobuf how to use FieldMaskUtil to merge proto objects without zero field?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protocols

[Protobuf-java: Merge two proto objects without concatenating repeated fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67921459/protobuf-java-merge-two-proto-objects-without-concatenating-repeated-fields)

I have found a similar question, but I need to filter all the zero values from the src field.

NewMerge(src, dest)

All src value fields with zero value in proto are not copied.

For example an int field `a = 0` or empty string field `b = ""` will not be copied.